# Is it possible to get the lagged value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do a comparison between documents in a MongoDB collection that has a time component. Let's assume the documents look like so:

```
{date: 2010-01-01, sales: 100}
{date: 2010-01-02, sales: 202}
{date: 2010-01-03, sales: 149}
```

Is it possible to lag the values for comparison? Is it possible to do some sort of running difference? Perhaps some projection allows for this result:

```
{date: 2010-01-01, sales: 100, previous_sales: Nan}
{date: 2010-01-02, sales: 202, previous_sales: 100}
{date: 2010-01-03, sales: 149, previous_sales: 202}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in mongodb.

There is a `$subtract` operator in its aggregation pipelining, but it is for fields in the same document.

You will have to do it outside mongodb, once you have fetched records.

Comment: Do you think this has to do with the fact that documents are not required to be uniform? Relational databases guarantee the existence of a field.